# Using Java API to Update Story Status in Version One

Tags: java, versionone

I am trying to update the Story in Version One tool using Java.

I am looking at the below GitHub for reference.

https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient

**Sample Code:**

```
V1Connector connector = V1Connector.withInstanceUrl("<Server Base URI>")
.withUserAgentHeader("AppName", "1.0").withAccessToken("1.rWM8lKLk+PnyFxkEWVX5Kl2u6Jk=").build();
IServices services = new Services(connector);
Oid storyId = services.getOid("Story:7617");
```

When i try to fetch the story based on ID, i am getting `UnKnown Asset Type : Story`.

Is there any simple way, can we update the Story status using Java?

Comment: It may be that the metadata is not being loaded since the message is complaining about Story as being an "unknown Asset". This could be a result of not being authenticated in VersionOne.  Confirm your access token by using an http client such as Chrome's Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: @MarkIrvin : I hope it was because of Proxy environment. now i tried using proxy and getting another exception.. could you please check the another question and update me please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550673/caused-by-org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: I think that it makes more sense to confirm if you have a proxy between your computer and VersionOne then proceed to the next step.  Your system admin could tell you, check your internet Options if you have a windows box. or log out of your VersionOne app, fire up an http sniffer and watch the traffic from your machine to your VersionOne server.  If you are lucky, you might find a 407 in the trace.

Comment: @MarkIrvin : hey Mark, after changing my code to get the VIConnector using Proxy provider, i am not getting the Connection Timed Out Error, Please check my other stackoverflow post.